# Getting around "final or effectively final" in inner classes gives very random results

Tags: java, lambda, parallel-processing

I am doing a programming class project for matrix multiplication of a 400 line matrix by itself. I have it working in sequential mode, the goal of the project is to write a parallel implementation.

I have the following code, of course when I try to reference the counter j in the inner class I get an error about how j must be "final or effectively final". I found this workaround to use a final array but change the first element, but it gives very unpredictable results, I would have expected this to count from 0 to 399 but it spits out numbers in random order and then duplicates a lot of numbers including 399 many times.

Any ideas how I can use the incremented counter in the inner class? The goal is to call the method to handle matrix multiplication for each line in the matrix within the inner class, as we are supposed to have as many threads as lines in the matrix. Thanks for any help!

Here's the code:

```
private static double parallelMatrixMultiply()
{
    // use the existing arrays A and B, multiply them together
    // use the parallel approach
    // Create a fixed thread pool with maximum of three threads
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numRows);

    final int[] counter = new int[]{0};

    // submit a new thread for each row in the matrix
    for (int j = 0; j < numRows ; j++)
    {
        // we can modify an element of an array that has been declared final
        counter[0] = j;
        // Submit runnable tasks to the executor
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {
                // set a task to multiply for each row here
                // will be replaced by a line to multiply each row of matrix
                System.out.println(counter[0]);
            }
        });
    }

    // Shut down the executor
    executor.shutdown();

    // return the value of the 1,1 position on zero notation
    //return matrixC.get(1).get(1); // return matrixC(1,1)
    return 42.0;
}
```

Comment: I did search and could not find this question based on parallel/threads, going back to bed soon thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`counter` is a final variable that you can use in your callback method. But the contents of the array are not final, and you keep changing them. When the `run()` method is called, it will look at whatever `counter[0]` is holding *at that moment*, not at the point in the loop when you called `execute`.

You would be better off doing this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < numRows ; j++) {
    final int finalj = j;
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(finalj);
        }
    });
}
```

which is to say, assigning the value of your loop counter to an *actually final* variable for the callback method to use.

Comment: Awesome, it works, it doesn't print out the numbers in order but in this case that is not relevant. To the other answer that appears to be deleted I will look into AtomicInteger but I am going to choose this answer as correct as soon as I am allowed to. THANKS!!!!!

Comment: My deleted answer pertained to the assumption that you'll change your counter *within* the executor task. If all you need is an immutable value for each task, then this answer is appropriate.